# Когда пытаюсь поставить фрон на сервер то получаю ошибку при создании символической ссылки, как исправить?

Tags: linux, развертывание, deploy, file-exists

Получаю вот такую ошибку....

```
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/crypto-version2.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/crypto-version2.conf
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/crypto-version2.conf'
: File exists
```

сама директория выглядит  так

```
user@user-ubuntu-edv:/etc/nginx/sites-available$ ls
crypro-test.conf  crypto.conf  crypto-version2.conf  default
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Ну так Вам пишет, что такая ссылка уже есть. Нельзя создать ее ещё раз. Что делать? Получить английский и либо проигнорировать эту ошибку, либо удалить crypto-version2.conf и сделать линк ещё раз

Comment: ```ln -fs ...``` - будет постоянно перезаписывать файл, параметр  `-f` означает `удалять существующие целевые файлы`